# Wired data communication among android tablet and peripheral device

Tags: android, usb, tcpclient, serial-communication, tcp-port

I have wireless TCPIP stack written for communication.
Now I want the wired data serial-communication from the android tablet to device (bidirectional data communication) using USB OTG cable. How do i achieve it ?
I have written some module using usbManager but can not test. Is there a way to setup TCPIP stock over USB. How do I get a static IP address ?  Lots of question under one, its my confusion and some guru cold help me to get over this confusion.

Comment: mask> did you find a solution yet?